# Visual Studio 2012 re-arranges or messes up HTML Tables

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, html-table

Visual Studio 2012 seems to occasionally completely reorganise the HTML tables in my aspx pages. It switches rows around, moves text boxes and labels into the wrong place and generally creates havoc. It doesn't always do this. The problem often seems to occur when I have pasted in some HTML from another file. But other times it just happens out of the blue.
It's very frustrating, as there is no automatic way of repairing it. I have to go in and manually move all the elements back into the correct places. Has anyone else experienced this?

If so, how can I stop it from happening? I can't find any posts about it here or elsewhere.
I've added an example of some of my HTML before and after this occurs.

Before:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <caption class="GridViewHeader" style="text-align: left">
                1. Indicate whether the patient has experienced each symptom listed...</caption>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left" class="GridViewHeader">
                    Symptom</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 150px;" class="GridViewHeader">
                    I have experienced this recently</td>
                <td class="GridViewHeader" style="width: 150px; text-align: center">This symptom is related to my blood pressure</td>
                <td class="GridViewHeader" style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">This symptom is related to the medicine I am taking for my high blood pressure</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left">
                    <strong>a.</strong> Pain</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 150px;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Pain" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList></td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Pain_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Pain_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left">
                    <strong>b.</strong> Sore throat</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 150px;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="SoreThroat" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList></td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="SoreThroat_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="SoreThroat_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left"><strong>c.</strong> Nausea</td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Nausea" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Nausea_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Nausea_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left"><strong>d.</strong> Breathlessness</td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Breathlessness" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Breathlessness_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Breathlessness_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left"><strong>e.</strong> Weight loss</td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="WeightLoss" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="WeightLoss_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="WeightLoss_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left"><strong>f.</strong> Fatigue</td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Fatigue" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Fatigue_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Fatigue_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left"><strong>g.</strong> Stiff joints</td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="StiffJoints" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="StiffJoints_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="StiffJoints_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left"><strong>h.</strong> Sore eyes</td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="SoreEyes" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="SoreEyes_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="SoreEyes_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

After:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <caption class="GridViewHeader">
                    1. Indicate whether the patient has experienced each symptom listed...</caption>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pain</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Pain" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Pain") %>' AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="symptom_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Pain_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Pain_RelatedToHighBP") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Pain_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Pain_RelatedToBPMeds") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="GridViewHeader"><strong>a.</strong> Symptom</td>
                    <td class="GridViewHeader">I have experienced this recently</td>
                    <td class="GridViewHeader">This symptom is related to my blood pressure</td>
                    <td class="GridViewHeader">This symptom is related to the medicine I am taking for my high blood pressure</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>c.</strong> Nausea</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Nausea" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Nausea") %>' AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="symptom_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Nausea_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Nausea_RelatedToHighBP") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Nausea_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Nausea_RelatedToBPMeds") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>b.</strong> Sore throat</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="SoreThroat" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("SoreThroat") %>' AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="symptom_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="SoreThroat_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("SoreThroat_RelatedToHighBP") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="SoreThroat_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("SoreThroat_RelatedToBPMeds") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>e.</strong> Weight loss</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="WeightLoss" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("WeightLoss") %>' AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="symptom_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="WeightLoss_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("WeightLoss_RelatedToHighBP") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="WeightLoss_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("WeightLoss_RelatedToBPMeds") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>d.</strong> Breathlessness</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Breathlessness" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Breathlessness") %>' AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="symptom_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Breathlessness_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Breathlessness_RelatedToHighBP") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Breathlessness_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Breathlessness_RelatedToBPMeds") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>g.</strong> Stiff joints</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="StiffJoints" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("StiffJoints") %>' AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="symptom_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="StiffJoints_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("StiffJoints_RelatedToHighBP") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="StiffJoints_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("StiffJoints_RelatedToBPMeds") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>f.</strong> Fatigue</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Fatigue" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Fatigue") %>' AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="symptom_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Fatigue_RelatedToHighBP" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Fatigue_RelatedToHighBP") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="Fatigue_RelatedToBPMeds" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Fatigue_RelatedToBPMeds") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Don&#39;t know</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```